# How to optimize this TSQL script (delete by iterating)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 70 000 tokens in an excel file. I have to use them to find and delete rows from a table. Table has about 4 million rows.

When I tried to run this script CPU usage went over the top. What is the best way to optimize it (like maybe split it into smaller transactions, batch delete, cursor etc.)?

Here is an example record from the table:
[image]

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE [name] like '#tokens%') 
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #tokens
END

CREATE TABLE #tokens(token nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #tokens(token) SELECT t.token FROM (VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc')) AS t(token) --- here would be more tokens inserted

DECLARE @command nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @token nvarchar(50)

WHILE ((select count(1) from #tokens) > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @token = token FROM #tokens

    SET @command = 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; delete from MyTable where token like ''%' + @token + '%''' --- has to be 'like' due to some different prefixes so it can be 'x.aaa' or 'y.aaa' or both
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @command
    
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    DELETE FROM #tokens WHERE token = @token
END

DROP TABLE #tokens
```

Comment: Asides: `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` means ... ? And see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). A parameter should be used instead of concatenating strings into executable SQL.

Comment: so to make it clear you need to delete ALL tokens from #tokens table in [MyTable]? why not to do left join and delete all at once (since you are not using any extra logic or filtering)?

Comment: @Power Mouse I have to delete all rows from MyTable where column [token] is like any token that I provide. There is also an additional condition to delete query apart from [token], which is another column has to have a particular value. I left it out as I felt it was not important to the whole.

Comment: @HABO Does a query with TOP 1 need ORDER BY? This script worked fine with less tokens.

Comment: What are the *actual* data and why is the query this way? [Row-By-Agonizing-Row](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) is the absolute slowest way to do anything. `LIKE '%' + @token + '%` is just as bad - `LIKE '%something%'` can't use any index and requires a full table scan. If you have a 100K row table you're forcing the server to perform 7M substring searches

Comment: There's no reason for dynamic SQL either, you could write `DELETE  MyTable where token like '%' + @token + '%'`. No matter what `@token` contains, it's never part of the SQL query itself. The query will remain as slow as ever but at least you won't risk SQL injection

Comment: When you say "it can be 'x.aaa' or 'y.aaa' or both" are you always just trying to extract some substring after the last dot and then use that in an equality?

Comment: On the other hand `LIKE 'banana%'` is essentially a range query looking for all values between `banana` and `bananb` exclusive. It *can* use indexes. So what are the actual data and logic?

Comment: @Martin Smith Basically. I am provided with a token (simple guid). I cannot search the column by exactly the guid, as it's saved with a prefix like 'x.{guid}'. Prefixes can be different so I cannot add some prefix to my guid and search exactly by it.

Comment: *"as it's saved with a prefix like 'x.{guid}'. Prefixes can be different"* Sounds like the GUID and prefix should be in different columns then; the design is the issue. If you need both values in the same column then use computed column.

Comment: How is the Guid represented? Is the right most 36 characters of the string the Guid? If you can extract this portion and then do an equality operation using it at least then you can get a hash or merge join that only processes each row once not a nested loops that can end up scanning each row many times

Comment: Or if you index `#tokens` a nested loops with the temp table on the inside of the join and an index seek https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AF1P.png

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos MartinSmith I added an example of data in this table.

Comment: Using `top` without `order by` is a way to give SQL Server some room to play. You're saying "surprise me". Although an `order by` clause is not required, it makes one wonder whether there was any consideration of the desired order or just an assumption that the results will appear in some particular order, e.g. as last seen with a `select` or the order in which rows were inserted. If you really don't care, adding a comment to that effect will inform Maintainers Of The Future: `-- Any order will do.`. Aside: You also don't need a precise count of rows for the `while` when `exists` will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clarified in the comments that the motivation for the `LIKE` was to match `{guid}` with `x.{guid}` when the prefix is unknown.

Assuming this is a one off task so you might not want to change the table structure to facilitate a one off operation then you can do.

```
--Primary key added for index
CREATE TABLE #tokens(token varchar(36) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO #tokens(token) 
SELECT t.token
FROM (VALUES ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'), 
             ('bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb'), 
             ('cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc')) AS t(token)

DELETE mt
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE RIGHT(mt.token,36) IN (SELECT t.token FROM #tokens t);
```

This changes the condition from a `LIKE` to an equality condition and means that hash join, merge join, or nested loops with `MyTable` as the *outer* table and an index seek on `#tokens` are all viable options rather than having to scan all 4 million rows in `MyTable` for every row in `#tokens`.

Comment: This looks good, thank you. I will be able to test it properly in right environment on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I need to place example for you here how to use LIKE in join condition.

```sql
declare @MyTable TABLE (token varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @MyTable(token)
VALUES
('qqq'),('qqqfyj'),('ffnhj'),('gfb'),('vvfb'),('qrre'),('ffe'),('ff')

DECLARE @tokensToDelete TABLE  (token varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @tokensToDelete (token)
VALUES
('qq'),('ff')


DELETE @MyTable
WHERE token IN (
    SELECT t.token
    FROM @MyTable t
LEFT JOIN @tokensToDelete d ON t.token LIKE CONCAT('%', d.token ,'%')
WHERE d.token IS NOT null
) 


SELECT * FROM @MyTable
```

Comment: `LIKE CONCAT('%', d.token ,'%')` is going to result in a *scan* of the entire table. There's no iteration now, which is good, but this could still be quite slow, due to the OP's design "choices".

Comment: @ThomA, i know. in addition, the whole "like" condition is resources hungry but  i try to show the approach to remove iteration..

Comment: But why a `LEFT` join, wouldn't an `INNER` join make more sense

Comment: @Charlieface you are correct,  but it was intentional, in case requestor will run select statement to see if need to add additional conditions.. etc.. (not production version lol)

Comment: Thank you! I tested it locally, will try in another environment on Monday.